# SVG en blanco | Angular

Tags: html, css, html5, angular, svg

tengo dos componentes que contienen graficos svg (etiquetas)

uno es un carrito de compras y el otro es un logo

ambos se quedan en blanco
al eliminar un subcomponente estos vuelven a mostrarse
les miestro
**Cabe destacar que Los svg ocupan su espacio en el DOM
los path por ejeplo mantienen su espacio dentro del svg, pero no muestran color ni forma**

```
<app-public-navbar [userLog]="userLog"></app-public-navbar>
<main class="page">
    <app-sidebar-home [auth]="userLog"></app-sidebar-home>
    <section class="cont">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </section>
</main>
<!- SVGs en Blanco ->

ESTE ES EL COMPONENTE QUE NO PERMITE SE MUESTRE LO MENCIONADO

<app-public-navbar [userLog]="userLog"></app-public-navbar>
<main class="page">
    <!-- <app-sidebar-home [auth]="userLog"></app-sidebar-home> -->
    <section class="cont">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </section>
</main>
<!-SVGs del navbar se muestra->


<section class="configuration-menu" #configurationMenu>

    <div class="menu-container-fixed-" #menuContainerFixed>

        <div class="heading">

            <svg version="1.1" id="menu-act-00" title="Menú" (click)="toggleMenu()" class="responsive--icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 400 400">

            <defs>
                <title>Menu Action</title>
                <style>
             
    
                   
                @keyframes rotarDesaparecer{
                    0%{
                        opacity: 1;
                        transform: scale(.4);
                    }
                     
                    100%{
                        transform: scale(2);
                        opacity: 0;
                    }
                }
                @keyframes rotarAparecer{
                    0%{
                        opacity:0;
                        transform: scale(2);
                    }
                     
                    100%{
                        opacity: 1;
                        transform: scale(1);

                    }
                }
                    .rotar-d{
                        animation-name: rotarDesaparecer;
                        animation-duration: .7s;
                        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
                        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                    }
                    .rotar-a{
                        animation-name: rotarAparecer;
                        animation-duration: .7s;
                        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
                        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            
                    }
                    .active{
                        opacity:1;
                    }
            
                    g{
                        opacity:0;
                        transition: .7s;
                        transform-origin: center 50%;
                    }
                     
                </style>
            </defs>
        
                <g  id="bars" class="bars active">
                    <path id="XMLID_3_" d="M367.1,86H32.9c-8.3,0-15-6.7-15-15V40.3c0-8.3,6.7-15,15-15h334.1c8.3,0,15,6.7,15,15V71
                        C382.1,79.2,375.4,86,367.1,86z"/>
                    <path id="XMLID_7_" d="M367.1,230.3H32.9c-8.3,0-15-6.7-15-15v-30.7c0-8.3,6.7-15,15-15h334.1c8.3,0,15,6.7,15,15v30.7
                        C382.1,223.6,375.4,230.3,367.1,230.3z"/>
                    <path id="XMLID_2_" d="M367.1,374.7H32.9c-8.3,0-15-6.7-15-15V329c0-8.3,6.7-15,15-15h334.1c8.3,0,15,6.7,15,15v30.7
                        C382.1,368,375.4,374.7,367.1,374.7z"/>
                </g>
                <g id="cross" class="cross" >
                    <path id="XMLID_12_" d="M368.6,316.8c7.1,7.1,7.1,18.5,0,25.6l-26.2,26.2c-7.1,7.1-18.5,7.1-25.6,0L200,251.8L83.2,368.6
                        c-7.1,7.1-18.5,7.1-25.6,0l-26.2-26.2c-7.1-7.1-7.1-18.5,0-25.6L148.2,200L31.4,83.2c-7.1-7.1-7.1-18.5,0-25.6l26.2-26.2
                        c7.1-7.1,18.5-7.1,25.6,0L200,148.2L316.8,31.4c7.1-7.1,18.5-7.1,25.6,0l26.2,26.2c7.1,7.1,7.1,18.5,0,25.6L251.8,200L368.6,316.8z
                        "/>
                </g>
     
            <script>
                let ___flag=false;
                const menuAct = document.getElementById('menu-act-00');
                
                const bars = document.getElementById('bars');
                const cross = document.getElementById('cross');
                menuAct.addEventListener('click',()=>{
                
                if(!___flag){
    
                    bars.classList.remove('rotar-a');
                    bars.classList.remove('active');
                    bars.classList.add('rotar-d');
                    
                    cross.classList.remove('rotar-d');
                    cross.classList.add('rotar-a');
                    cross.classList.add('active');              
                    ___flag=!___flag;
                    
                }else{
    
                    bars.classList.remove('rotar-d');
                    bars.classList.add('rotar-a');
                    bars.classList.add('active');
                    
                    cross.classList.remove('rotar-a');  
                    cross.classList.remove('active');               
    
                    cross.classList.add('rotar-d');
                    ___flag=!___flag;
                    
                }
                            },false);
                
            </script>
    </svg>
            <h2>Menú</h2>

        </div>


        <ul class="items-menu">

            <li class="item pointer" RouterLinkActive="active">
                <svg class="responsive--icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M464 32H48C21.49 32 0 53.49 0 80v352c0 26.51 21.49 48 48 48h416c26.51 0 48-21.49 48-48V80c0-26.51-21.49-48-48-48zm-6 400H54a6 6 0 0 1-6-6V86a6 6 0 0 1 6-6h404a6 6 0 0 1 6 6v340a6 6 0 0 1-6 6zm-42-92v24c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12H204c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-24c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h200c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12zm0-96v24c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12H204c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-24c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h200c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12zm0-96v24c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12H204c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-24c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h200c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12zm-252 12c0 19.882-16.118 36-36 36s-36-16.118-36-36 16.118-36 36-36 36 16.118 36 36zm0 96c0 19.882-16.118 36-36 36s-36-16.118-36-36 16.118-36 36-36 36 16.118 36 36zm0 96c0 19.882-16.118 36-36 36s-36-16.118-36-36 16.118-36 36-36 36 16.118 36 36z"/></svg>
                <p>
                    <app-category-link class="caltegory-link"></app-category-link>
                </p>
            </li>
            <li class="item pointer" *ngIf="!auth" RouterLinkActive="active" id="registrarme" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
                <svg class="responsive--icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 640 512"><path d="M624 208h-64v-64c0-8.8-7.2-16-16-16h-32c-8.8 0-16 7.2-16 16v64h-64c-8.8 0-16 7.2-16 16v32c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16h64v64c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16h32c8.8 0 16-7.2 16-16v-64h64c8.8 0 16-7.2 16-16v-32c0-8.8-7.2-16-16-16zm-400 48c70.7 0 128-57.3 128-128S294.7 0 224 0 96 57.3 96 128s57.3 128 128 128zm89.6 32h-16.7c-22.2 10.2-46.9 16-72.9 16s-50.6-5.8-72.9-16h-16.7C60.2 288 0 348.2 0 422.4V464c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h352c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48v-41.6c0-74.2-60.2-134.4-134.4-134.4z"/></svg>
                <p>Registrarse</p>
            </li>
            <li class="item pointer" [routerLink]="['/login']" *ngIf="!auth" RouterLinkActive="active">
                <svg class="responsive--icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 496 512"><path d="M248 104c-53 0-96 43-96 96s43 96 96 96 96-43 96-96-43-96-96-96zm0 144c-26.5 0-48-21.5-48-48s21.5-48 48-48 48 21.5 48 48-21.5 48-48 48zm0-240C111 8 0 119 0 256s111 248 248 248 248-111 248-248S385 8 248 8zm0 448c-49.7 0-95.1-18.3-130.1-48.4 14.9-23 40.4-38.6 69.6-39.5 20.8 6.4 40.6 9.6 60.5 9.6s39.7-3.1 60.5-9.6c29.2 1 54.7 16.5 69.6 39.5-35 30.1-80.4 48.4-130.1 48.4zm162.7-84.1c-24.4-31.4-62.1-51.9-105.1-51.9-10.2 0-26 9.6-57.6 9.6-31.5 0-47.4-9.6-57.6-9.6-42.9 0-80.6 20.5-105.1 51.9C61.9 339.2 48 299.2 48 256c0-110.3 89.7-200 200-200s200 89.7 200 200c0 43.2-13.9 83.2-37.3 115.9z"/></svg>
                <p>Iniciar Sesión</p>
            </li>
            <li class="item pointer" RouterLinkActive="active">
                <svg id="icon-cart-list" class="responsive--icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-291 414.9 12 12">                 
           <g>
               <path d="M-279.8,425.2h-0.7c-0.1-0.7-0.7-1.3-1.5-1.3s-1.4,0.5-1.5,1.3h-2.3c-0.1-0.7-0.7-1.3-1.5-1.3c-0.7,0-1.3,0.5-1.4,1.1
                   c-0.5-0.2-0.8-0.6-0.8-1.1c0-0.6,0.5-1.1,1.1-1.2l0,0.1c0,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.3h6.8c0.2,0,0.3-0.1,0.4-0.3l1.1-4.5c0,0,0-0.1,0-0.1
                   c0-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.4h-8.7l-0.3-1.2c0-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.3h-1.1c-0.2,0-0.4,0.2-0.4,0.4c0,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.4,0.4h0.8l1.2,4.8
                   c-0.9,0.2-1.6,1-1.6,1.9c0,0.9,0.6,1.7,1.5,1.9c0.2,0.6,0.7,1.1,1.4,1.1c0.7,0,1.3-0.5,1.4-1.1h2.4c0.2,0.6,0.8,1.1,1.4,1.1
                   s1.3-0.5,1.4-1.1h0.8c0.2,0,0.3-0.1,0.3-0.3C-279.5,425.3-279.6,425.2-279.8,425.2z M-287.3,422.4h-0.5l-0.4-1.5h0.8V422.4z
                    M-282,418.6h1.4l-0.4,1.5h-1V418.6z M-282,420.9h0.8l-0.4,1.5h-0.5V420.9z M-284.3,418.6h1.5v1.5h-1.5V418.6z M-284.3,420.9h1.5
                   v1.5h-1.5V420.9z M-286.5,418.6h1.5v1.5h-1.5V418.6z M-286.5,420.9h1.5v1.5h-1.5V420.9z M-288.6,418.6h1.4v1.5h-1L-288.6,418.6z
                    M-287.3,426.1c-0.4,0-0.8-0.3-0.8-0.8s0.3-0.8,0.8-0.8s0.8,0.3,0.8,0.8S-286.8,426.1-287.3,426.1z M-282,426.1
                   c-0.4,0-0.8-0.3-0.8-0.8s0.3-0.8,0.8-0.8s0.8,0.3,0.8,0.8S-281.6,426.1-282,426.1z"/>
           </g>
           </svg>

                <p>Mi Compra</p>
            </li>

            <!-- ============================================================== -->
            <!-- Profile -->
            <!-- ============================================================== -->
            <li class="item navbar-collapse " *ngIf="auth">
                <!-- <a class=" p-0 " href="" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> -->
                <img src="assets/img/avatar.svg" alt="user" class="m-0 responsive--icon profile-pic" /><span class="dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-dark" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Mi usuario</span>
                <!-- </a> -->
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right mt-2 animated flipInY">
                    <ul class="dropdown-user">
                        <li>
                            <div class="dw-user-box display-flex align-items-center" align="center">
                                <div class="u-img"><img src="assets/img/avatar.svg" alt="user"></div>
                                <div class="u-text">
                                    <h4 class="name-user OpenSans-700 text-left">
                                        Nombre Usuario
                                    </h4>
                                    <p class="text-muted">
                                        email Usuario
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="a-menu-user nav-link OpenSans-400" routerLink="/perfil">

                                <img class="mr-2" src="../../../assets/img/iconos/icons-main/icons/person.svg" alt="" width="18" height="18" title="Person"> Perfil
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
                            <a class="a-menu-user nav-link OpenSans-400" [routerLink]="['/account']">

                                <img class="mr-2" src="../../../assets/img/iconos/icons-main/icons/gear.svg" alt="" width="18" height="18" title="Configuración"> Configuración de tu cuenta

                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">

                            <a class="a-menu-user nav-link OpenSans-400">

                                <img class="mr-2" src="../../../assets/img/iconos/icons-main/icons/power.svg" alt="" width="18" height="18" title="Logout"> Salir

                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <!-- ============================================================== -->
            <!-- END Profile -->
            <!-- ============================================================== -->
        </ul>

    </div>


</section>
 
POSEE ESTOS METODOS
```

el svg dentro de app-sidebar tambien se deja demostrar (el mismo que dejaparece junto al logo)
son la misma figura pero ambos estan dotados de "propiedades diferentes"

@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
public fixedMenu( $event: Event){

```
const menuContainerFixed = this.menuContainerFixed.nativeElement;
const pxTopElement = menuContainerFixed.offsetTop;
const pxTopDocument = document.documentElement.scrollTop;

if ( pxTopDocument > pxTopElement ) {
  menuContainerFixed.classList.add( 'responsive-menu-container--fixed' );
} else {
  menuContainerFixed.classList.remove( 'responsive-menu-container--fixed' );
}
```

}

public toggleMenu(){
this.configurationMenu.nativeElement.classList.toggle( 'configuration-menu--responsive-expanded' );
}

````
Al eliminar este elemento aparacen los graficos nuevamente
```<svg id="menu-act-00" class="responsive--icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 400 400">```
````

Comment: Es complicado ayudarte viendo solo ese código. Te recomiendo que hagas un [mre] tal vez usando stackblitz

Comment: ok, agradecido!! es mi primera cosulta como tal

Comment: Amigo ya edite, olvide poner ese pequeño pero importantisimo detalle
los svg ocupan su espacio e incluso los elementos internos de el

Comment: amigo al eliminar este elemento svg(completo) dentro del aside vuelven los graficos
<svg id="menu-act-00" class="responsive--icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 400 400">

Comment: En el svg del menu (☰) tienes en el CSS`.active{ opacity:1; }  g{opacity:0;...` En el svg del carrito tienes un grupo sin ninguna clase que por lo tanto ttendrá `opacity:0;`. Y sí: el CSS que aparece dentro de un elemento svg afecta a todo el documento .